# Is There a R function in tidyverse to select elements of a column using codes?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two data frame as follows:

Dataframe 1

```html
df1 <- read.table(text = " Place Code Name
A 12 Hogo
                  C 14 Smith
                  C 17 Rose
                  D 16 John
                  A 19 Noor
                  B 12 Hogo
                  C 16 John
                  D 19 Noor
                  A 24 Matt
                  D 23 Kim
                  ", header = TRUE)
```

Dataframe 2

```html
df2 <- read.table(text = " Code Name
Code Name
12 Hogo
14 Smith
17 Rose
16 John
19 Noor
24 Matt
", header = TRUE)
```

I want to select A and C based on codes as follows

```html
Place  Code Name
A 12 Hogo
C 14 Smith
C 17 Rose
C 16 John
A 19 Noor
A 24 Matt
```

I have searched and I failed to find a solution. Your help very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do a join?

Comment: Try with `left_join(df2, df1)`

Comment: Can't you just do filter(df1, Place %in% c("A", "C")) ?

Comment: @User20100, even though you have two data frames, a left_join() joining on the code will solve your problem as akrun said above

Comment: to add to akrun ```left_join(df2, df1) %>% filter(Place %in% c("A","C")```

Comment: @User20100 Literally just run the above code provided by akrun and jeffverboon

Comment: convert one of the columns to the same data type as the other

Comment: @User20100: You are getting this error because you are listing column names `Code` and `Name` twice in your definition of `df2`. Fix the definition and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is happening because in DF2 you have the column names two time (as shown out by  Artem Sokolov), and R is reading code in as Factors and not integers values.

```
 df2 <- read.table(text = " Code Name
    12  Hogo
    14  Smith
    17  Rose
    16  John
    19  Noor
    24  Matt
    ", header = TRUE)
```

Then run the join and you should be fine.